# How to interpret linux kernel trap error line?

Tags: c, linux, debugging

I have a socket application written in C++ which runs on Linux. It crashed this morning and when I check the /var/log/messages I see the following line at the time of the crash:

```
kernel: traps: LogProcessor[9364] general protection ip:4f2555 sp:7fbd529b1670 error:0 in MyPrg[400000+21a000]
```

I want to dig into the code and find the reason but I don't know how to interpret the values in the error line.
Does it mean the error is caused by LogProcessor? What are the values "ip", "sp", "error:0", MyPrg[400000+21a000] ?

Answer (score 5):

This is [General Protection Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault). There are multiple reasons that can cause it. You can read more in the aforementioned link.

- `LogProcessor[9364]` - thread name and pid
- `ip:4f2555` - instruction pointer (looks suspicious here)
- `sp:7fbd529b1670` - stack pointer
- `error:0` - error code (why 0?)
- `MyPrg[400000+21a000]` - program name

Answer (score 4):

The most meaningful information is Instruction Pointer (IP). You can examine your binary with GNU tools and check what happened. For example with addr2line

```sh
addr2line -e <your binary> 0x4f2555
```

If your application was build with debug symbols (-g) and if fault happened in your code (not library), output should show you the problem.

SP is Stack Pointer at the time of the crash. MyPrg[400000+21a000] tells you Virtual Address of binary.

error:0 means dividing by zero (if your application works on x86 architecture):
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/traps.h#n148